# ASP.NET sending with Gmail smtp overrides From Address

Tags: asp.net, smtp, gmail

I was trying to send from a aspx page a mail message using the smtp gmail (we are google apps customers and I tried with a paid account and with a free gmail...)
I was able to send the messagge setting credentials, port, ssl, etc. but what is wrong is the From address of the message. Indeed, the mail is coming always from the address of the auth user and not from what I set in the msg.From property...

Eg. the mail arrives with from "myaccount@gmail.com" and not from sender@somedomain.com

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("sender@somedomain.com", "sender name");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@somedomain.com","recipient name"));
msg.Subject = "subject";
msg.Body = "some body";

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaccount@gmail.com", "*******");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

smtp.Send(msg);
```

Is there a setting to avoid this ?

thanks in advance

Sandro

Answer (score 0):

Check the message headers.
Depending on your email client, here's the instructions how to reach them: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en

You'll see, that FROM field is only for indication of the sender's name.
It can be ignored by email client, especially, if it contains address different than real sender's address.

Comment: Mike, thanks for your answer; I checked the msg header but the sender email address (sender@somedomain.com in my example) never appears. It appearrs the name, but NOT his email. Only the myaccount@gmail.com who is the auth user. So obviously any client could substitute it...